# Carathéodory measurability condition for finite outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu^*$ be a **finite** outer measure on a set $\Omega$.

I read that the Carathéodory measurability condition simplifies to $\mu^*(E)+\mu^*(\Omega\smallsetminus E)=\mu^*(\Omega)$. Is it correct?

EDIT  An [answer in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34029/57467) contains exactly this claim (52 upvotes, but no proof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Exercise 4 on page 15 of this file. [link](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT2400/v13/mathanalch6.pdf)
It's a guided exercise to your question.

Comment: Thank you, excellent notes.